# Change datatype for column in a select query

Tags: sql

I would like to change the data type from "text" to "number" in a `select` query.

This is my select query.

```
SELECT
    "customers"."id",
    "customers"."name",
    "customers"."Antal beregninger",
    "customers"."Status",
    "Afgiftsberegner - Antal beregninger pr. Forhandler - SQL"."count(id)"
FROM  
    "customers"
```

I would like to change this column to "number" datatype:

```
"customers"."Antal beregninger"
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Why do you store antal beregninger in a text column instead of a integer column?

Comment: On a side note: It can ease database handling a lot not to use any names that need quotes. Just  `customers.antal_beregninger` would be a simple table and column name, where you don't have to remember what upper lower/case must be used when using the names.

Answer (score 0):

you did not specify the DBMS you're using but `CAST` might be your friend here, if your DBMS supports it:

```
SELECT
    "customers"."id",
    "customers"."name",
    CAST("customers"."Antal beregninger" AS numeric) AS "Antal beregninger",
    "customers"."Status",
    "Afgiftsberegner - Antal beregninger pr. Forhandler - SQL"."count(id)"
FROM
    "customers";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CAST function

```
SELECT
    "customers"."id",
    "customers"."name",
    CAST("customers"."Antal beregninger" AS INTEGER) AS "Antal beregninger",
    "customers"."Status",
    "Afgiftsberegner - Antal beregninger pr. Forhandler - SQL"."count(id)"
FROM  
    "customers"
```

In this modified query, CAST("customers"."Antal beregninger" AS INTEGER) converts the "Antal beregninger" column to an integer. If you need a different numeric type (like DECIMAL, FLOAT, etc.), you can replace INTEGER with the desired type.

Answer (score -1):

In T SQL you can add 0 to your text and thanks to implicit casting and data type precedance the text will become an integer. A visible effect will be that leading zeros will be dropped.

Something like the below:

```
Select [Antal beregninger] + 0 From customers
```